# How to read the text-file containing list of lists when the list is like [(81, 134), (176, 134)]

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, int, tuples

I am trying to read the text-file containing a list of lists containing tuples of coordinates. How do I read the file so that I would get a list of lists?

The sample content of the text file is,

> [(75, 143), (187, 138)]
>
> [(85, 140), (193, 134)]
>
> [(65, 120)]
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

I tried to read the file using the code below. It is able to read the file. But it is storing it in 'x' as str rather than a list. How to convert it to list?

```py
filename1 = 'testfile.txt'

m_text = open(Filename1,'r+')

m_List = []

with open(Filename1) as mf:

    x = mf.readlines()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: I am not sure if that is applicable in my case. Could you suggest a specific solution out of the solutions if you believe it exists in this link?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code output comes like this, a list consist of string represented list with `\n` at end of each element and single `\n`.

```
['[(75, 143), (187, 138)]\n', '\n', '[(85, 140), (193, 134)]\n', '\n', '[(65, 120)]\n']
```

To convert that to list you need to remove thos `\n` from each element. and convert back to python list. This can be done using `lambda`,`map`, `strip`, `eval` functions and `list comprehension` which is a powerful feature of python.

```py
filename1 = 'testfile.txt'
m_List = []
with open(file=filename1, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as mf:
    x = mf.readlines()
    m_List = [cordinate for cordinate in list(map(lambda i: eval(str(i).strip()) if str(i).strip() else None, x)) if cordinate]
    print(m_List)
```

Gives output:

```
[[(75, 143), (187, 138)], [(85, 140), (193, 134)], [(65, 120)]]
```